# Why does embedded \g@addto@macro sometimes fail?

Tags: macros, expansion

I decided to test my understanding of expansion and embed `\g@addto@macro` within another three macros.

```
\g@addto@macro
  \appendmacro
    \layertwo
      \activatelayerone
```

From my understanding, the output in the log for my example below should be:

```
  ==> item1item2\item \undefinedmacroA item5\undefinedmacroB
```

But in reality, it is:

```
  ==> item1item2\item \undefinedmacroA \undefinedmacroB
```

## Example

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\macrolist{}

\makeatletter
\def\appendmacro#1{%
  \g@addto@macro\macrolist{#1}
}%
\makeatother

\def\activatelayerone#1{%
  \def\layertwo##1{%
    \appendmacro{##1}
  }%
}%

\begin{document}
\null
\appendmacro{item1}
\appendmacro{item2}
\appendmacro{\unexpanded{\item}} % Demonstrate that \unexpanded must be called by the sender
\appendmacro{\unexpanded{\undefinedmacroA}}
\activatelayerone
\layertwo{item5}
\layertwo{\unexpanded{\undefinedmacroB}}
\typeout{ ==> \macrolist}
\end{document}
```

Comment: unrelated probably but you are missising `%` from ends of lines again

Comment: `\activatelayerone` takes an argument ...

Comment: @JosephWright DOH! Right when I think I am getting it, I make a rookie mistake like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\def\activatelayerone#1{%
  \def\layertwo##1{%
    \appendmacro{##1}
  }%
}%
```

Apart from defining `\layertwo` to be append and add a spurious space because of the missing `%`, this acts as `\@gobble` to discard the next token as `#1` is not used. Here the next token is `\layertwo` so that is discarded and `{item5}` is just typeset at that point.